# SwiftUI MacOSX ImagePicker

Tags: swift, xcode, image, swiftui

I am creating a Mac OSX app with SwiftUI. I want to have a ImagePicker/ File Picker (only Image types) to select a Image from the File System and to display it in my `Image()`.

I couldn't find the correct way of doing it. I am used to UIImagePicker in iOS with ObjectiveC. What is the correct way of doing it?

Just to give you a example, I have a button and want to call the ImagePicker on Button press.

[image]

Apple contacts book is using this kind of modal view. Is that available for us too?

Answer (score 11):

SwiftUI in macOS

```
import SwiftUI

struct FileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Select File") {
            let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
            openPanel.prompt = "Select File"
            openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
                openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
                openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
                openPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png","jpg","jpeg"]
                openPanel.begin { (result) -> Void in
                    if result.rawValue == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK.rawValue {
                        let selectedPath = openPanel.url!.path
                        print(selectedPath)

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple example for most usage.

Answer (score 3):

I used the IKPictureTaker from Quarz for this.

```
image
    .gesture(
        TapGesture().onEnded{
        let imageChooser: IKPictureTaker = IKPictureTaker.pictureTaker()
        imageChooser.runModal()
        self.image = Image(nsImage: imageChooser.outputImage())
     }
```

Comment: Thank you !! This is the exact dialogue I was searching for!!

Answer (score 1):

initialize the panel like this:

```
let myFiledialog = NSOpenPanel()
myFiledialog.prompt = “Select path”
```

to add a selectbox like you want you need to add this:

```
myFiledialog.worksWhenModal = true
myFiledialog.canChooseDirectories = false
myFiledialog.canChooseFiles = true
```

you can select the datatype of your choice with

```
myFiledialog.allowedFileTypes = [“png”, “jpg”, “jpeg”]
```

to disable the multiselect add this.

```
myFiledialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

i hope this helped you.

Comment: Thanks :) NSOpenPanel works as requested. And the allowedFileTypes is perfect